# How to add custom packages in ubuntu setup?

Tags: ubuntu

For ubuntu how can I add custom packages like php, apache2 etc in the setup ISO so that they install along with my ubuntu setup next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look there:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

It is quite a lot of work though, and unless you need to install a lot of machines, it is probably not worth it.